# What is the "Angular root folder"

Tags: angular, mean-stack

Im trying to follow a tutorial on how to write a simple angular/mongodb CRUD-Application and im stuck at this part:

"Inside the angular root folder, create one folder called api and go inside that folder. Remember, it will be a completely separate project from Angular. So its node_modules are different from an Angular."

The question basically is where i should create the folder in my angular project :/

Heres the link for more context if needed: https://appdividend.com/2018/11/04/angular-7-crud-example-mean-stack-tutorial/

My proposal:

```
AngularApp    
   New Folder
      e2e
      node_modules
      (rest of angular project)    
   Api
```

Comment: That is root of your project. You will change angular.json there.

Comment: So if i have my folder structure like this:
U:\Projects\AngularProject\e2e, node_modules, etc...
Then i should create the "api" folder in U:\Projects?

Comment: No, in U:\Projects\AngularProject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they have different node modules, then they should have different package.json files.

Given that this file is at the root of the project, that's not possible.

You should have **ONE FOLDER** containing **TWO FOLDERS** :

- **api**
- **client**

That's the monorepo structure. For more information, you can take a look at Narwhal's team latest, [NxDev](https://nx.dev/)

**EDIT**

Your proposal is

```
AngularApp
  Api
```

Mine is

```
MyMeanApp
  AngularApp
  Api
```

Comment: So if I have an "AngularApp" folder which contains the normal project files like node_modules and src etc. do i just create a new folder inside the "AngularApp" folder and move everything into that, then create the api folder inside of the "AngularApp" folder?

Comment: No, you create a new folder where you put your "AngularApp" folder, and **as a sibling**, you create your "api" folder. They should not be one into another, but separated.

Comment: Wouldnt that be the same?

Comment: No you didn't understand me correctly / my explaination was bad, see my edit... However thanks, you really helped me

Comment: @niehoelzz that's the same answer as mine, except for the folder names, but yes, this is what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are following is making seperate front end and back end folders in one project.
You can go with this however you can add modules in one folder as well.

Yes, you can create folder like you are creating right now.